# WSL installation is failing with error code 0x80248014

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

My WSL installation on windows10 is failing with below error code .

```
>wsl.exe --install -d Ubuntu
Installing: Ubuntu
An error occurred during installation. Distribution Name: 'Ubuntu' Error Code: 0x80248014
```

I don't understand this error code. what exactly this error indicating?

Comment: Have you asked Microsoft support ?

Comment: have same issue

Comment: This is a Windows error code that suggests you have corruption in your SoftwareDistribution folder on Windows and an error with Updates in general.  Unfortunately, debugging that error requires Windows support, and we can't assist you with the Windows error codes themselves.

Comment: If this is a work/business computer you may have security restrictions in place which are preventing access to Windows Store. You can check by running Windows Store from the Start button and see what comes up.

Answer (score 4):

This error, usually means a fault with Windows Update.
According to [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1764990/error-0x80244018-installing-any-linux-distribution-under-wsl). You can bypass installing WSL through Windows update by using the `--web-download` switch:

```sh
wsl.exe --install --web-download Ubuntu
```

You should probably also look into why your Windows Update might be damaged, probably a good idea to run the standard repair commands from cmd:

```
sfc /scannow
DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
chkdsk C: /scan /forceofflinefix
```